# How to add servers to an exist vm group in terraform vsphere provider

Tags: terraform, provider, vsphere

If my cluster has a vm group named “test”, my code is

```
resource “vsphere_compute_cluster_vm_group” “cluster_vm_group” {
  name               = "test"
  compute_cluster_id = data.vsphere_compute_cluster.cluster.id
 virtual_machine_ids = vsphere_virtual_machine.vm .*.id
}
```

I got the error :

> **Error: A specified parameter was not correct: groupSpec.info.name
>
> on .terraform/modules/example-server-windowsvm/main.tf line 291, in
> resource “vsphere_compute_cluster_vm_group” “cluster_vm_group”: 291:
> resource “vsphere_compute_cluster_vm_group” “cluster_vm_group” {**

If input the name not exist such as test01, it will run successfully

Comment: Not sure, but if you are using the quotes as from the question, that might be the issue.

Comment: thanks @Marko E , it's copy issue, quotes in vscode is right